# How to measure the output voltage of a half wave, bridge and center tapped rectifier circuit using a multimeter and also a signal on oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, rectifier, multimeter

I am pretty new in electronics. I am curious about how to test the output voltage of the rectifier using DMM. Where to put the lead to get the voltage from a circuit. Do I have to measure it across the resistor?

Now if I insert a capacitor and a voltage regulator then from where should I start measuring? Where should I place the lead to get the values of this three rectifier?

Also I want to see them in oscilloscope display.

I hope someone will come up with a way to do it

Comment: Draw some schematics of what you're doing.   Schematics are how electronics people describe circuits.  Words are clear in your head, not ours.   There's a schematic editing tool built into this website ... You'll see it in the toolbar while you're editing your question

Comment: Let me give you this one important warning before you do anything - Do not connect your oscilloscope ground clip to the (-) of your bridge rectifier if it's rectifying AC voltage straight from the wall (i.e. no transformer).   Ask me how I know....

Comment: You don't "have to" measure anything. Measure what you *want to*, by connecting the DMM to the two points you want to know the difference between.

Comment: i researched before but it said we can use grounding on negative but why its not good to use the grounding there???

Answer (score 1):

Whether using a multimeter or oscilliscope, you always measure between two points in a circuit.

We normally choose a point in the circuit to use as a common reference point, or Zero Volts (often called "Ground" although it usually has no connection to the Earth).  We connect the black lead of the multimeter or "ground" clip of the oscilliscope to this Zero Volt/reference point and connect the red lead of the meter, or the tip of the oscilliscope probe to the point whose voltage we want to measure.

Comment: Thank you. But what if we use a voltage regulator and a capacitor at the same time? does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how.

**1. Half-wave**

[image]

**2. Full-wave with centre-tap**

[image]

**3. Full-wave bridge**

[image]

Comment: So, for all of the circuit we have to measure the output voltage across the load resistor right?

Comment: You may measure the no load or the load voltage without or with the load respectively.